# Museo del Calzado in Mexico City: Still in business?

Tags: museums, mexico-city

A few hits on the Internet mention "Museo del Calzado" (Shoe Museum) in Mexico City, but I find it hard to believe that not more information is available about it.

Is it a real museum, visitable as of 2015?

I am not looking for the museum in Spain with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is just a shoe shop that has a [small "museum"](http://www.elborcegui.com.mx/museo.htm).

It is at `Bolívar 27, Col. Centro  Histórico`.

By the way, this is the (different) place that Google Maps gives:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That'd be the one [mentioned on Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mexico_City/Centro#Museums):

> Museo del Calzado (Shoe Museum), Bolivar 27, 1st Floor. Private
>   collection of old shoes from the 18th, 19th and 20th century. The
>   museum belongs to the shoe store "El Borcegui", established in 1865
>   and **still selling shoes today**.

I found a [blog from 2008](http://www.ruthincondechi.com/2008/09/museo-del-calzado-shoe-museum.html) (with a comment in 2009) also about going there.

And [Visit Mexico](https://www.visitmexico.com/en/museums-in-mexico) (the tourism website) still has it listed on their museums page, so it's almost certainly open.